# Generating TinyMCE drop-down menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to create toolbar button in TinyMCE with options that are derived from the array.  I've followed the examples on Tiny's website and the button is getting generated as expected.  Here is the code:

```js
var mergeFields = {one: "first", two: "second", three: "third"};

tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
menubar: false,
toolbar: 'mergefields',
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('mergefields', {
        text: 'Merge Fields',
        fetch: function (callback) {
            var items = [];
            for (var fieldName in mergeFields) {
                var menuItem = {
                    type: 'menuitem',
                    text: mergeFields[fieldName],
                    onAction: function() {
                        // The problem: this function always inserts the last element of the array
                        // instead of the expected fieldName associated with this menuItem
                        editor.insertContent(fieldName);
                    },
                };
                items.push(menuItem);
            }
            callback(items);
        },
    });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=XXXXX"></script>

<textarea>Editor</textarea>
```

The problem happens when one of the options is selected and the anonymous function assigned to onAction property is executed -- it always inserts "three" into the document (presumably because after running through the whole array, fieldName is set to "three").  How can I make the onAction handler insert the right value into the document?

**This needs to work in TinyMCE 5.**

I've found a similar question here: [Adding custom dropdown menu to tinyMCE and insert dynamic contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803619/), but it was referring to TinyMCE 4 and unfortunately the provided answer does not work for TinyMCE 5.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Need a better understanding of the expected behavior. When the script runs it's set to three because that's the last value and each iteration of the loop overwrites the previous value.

Comment: The script creates a drop-down menu with three options.  When the first option is clicked, it needs to insert "one" into the document (second option needs to insert "two").  Instead it always inserts "three".

Comment: In the question you referenced, the answer provided a fiddle. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: The value three is always used because fieldName is a variable in the scope of the closure (which is the function fetch). fieldName is hoisted to the top of its scope and assumes the value of the last iteration. onAction is called after the loop has executed and hence fieldName is always three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I solved it using value+onSetup

https://jsfiddle.net/stvakis/tjh7k20v/8/

```
var mergeFields = {
  one: "first",
  two: "second",
  three: "third"
};

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: 'mergefields',
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('mergefields', {
      text: 'Merge Fields',
      fetch: function(callback) {
        var items = [];
        for (var fieldName in mergeFields) {
          var menuItem = {
            type: 'menuitem',
            text: mergeFields[fieldName],
            value:fieldName,
            onSetup: function(buttonApi) {
              var $this = this;
              this.onAction = function() {
                editor.insertContent($this.data.value);
              };
            },
          };
          items.push(menuItem);
        }
        callback(items);
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This works very well, solved my similar problem also. In my case, I kept the index of my more complex objects in the array in the value field of the menu item and with this I retrieved the correct item in onAction. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The proposed answer from StVakis causes strange behaviour of the menu items in my case (tinymce 5.10.3).

Instead using the value attribute, you can use the meta hash attribute. In this hash you can set as many attributes as you want.

```
{
  type: "menuitem",
  text: "My text",
  meta: {
    someVar: "I am " + i
  },
  onSetup: function(_) {
    var $this = this;
    this.onAction = function(_) {
      console.log($this.data.meta.someVar);
    };
  },
}
```